# javascript button not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

The following code creates a blue button at one end of a table row that links to a detail page for the client that you are one (the row you are on). This code works in Firefox but in Internet Explorer no buttons show, so you cannot get to the detail page. Can someone suggest a solution to this that would work in both IE and Firefox?

```
$('#account-table tbody tr').each( function () {
            //nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<a href="../two/'+this.id+'"><button class="btn   btn-mini btn-primary" type="button">Detail</button></a>';
            nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<a href="'+this.id+'"><button class="btn btn-mini   btn-primary" type="button">Detail</button></a>';
            nCloneTd.id = "detail_cell";
            nCloneTd.className = "center";
            nCloneTd.bgColor = "white"
            this.insertBefore(  nCloneTd.cloneNode( true ),   this.childNodes[this.childNodes.length] );
          });
```

Comment: `'<a href="'` seems like it wouldn't work.  Perhaps `""<a href="""`?

Comment: Better use document.createElement to create anchor and button and use nCloneTd.appendChild to add it to the TD.

Comment: the last statement: shouldn't it be this.appendChild(...) instead of this.insertBefore?

Comment: @ManofSnow No, I am pretty sure that what he has is what he wants.  As to the question, which version of IE are you using?  I know some don't support `insertBefore`.  Can you tell us what the DevTools say in the console?

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, why not continue by using `var nCloneTd = $('<a href= ... ')` and then `$(this).append(nCloneTd)` or `$(this).prepend(...)`?

Comment: Instead use nClodeTd = $("<a>", { id: "myID", "class": "myClass" });

Comment: IE version is 10.0.4.

Comment: With respect to the comment by Albert Xing, I did not write this code but inherited it in a project we are working on.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing 
`nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<a href="'+this.id+'"><button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="button">Detail</button></a>';`

---

to `nCloneTd.innerHTML = "<a href='"+this.id+"'><button class='btn btn-mini btn-primary' type='button'>Detail</button></a>";`

Comment: Doesn't work. Buttons do not display with this change either.